# Determining the fastest route from x key to y key in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, shortest-path

How would one make the fastest possible way to get from key x to key y in dictionary assuming that all of them are connected via their array values.

```
network={
 1: [3],
 2: [4],
 3: [1, 8, 7, 6, 4],
 4: [2, 3, 6, 5],
 5: [4, 11, 10],
 6: [3, 11, 4],
 7: [3, 8, 11],
 8: [3, 16, 9, 7],
 9: [8, 16, 14, 11],
 10: [5, 11, 13],
 11: [5, 6, 7, 9, 14, 10],
 12: [13],
 13: [10, 14, 12],
 14: [9, 16, 13, 11],
 15: [16],
 16: [8, 15, 14, 9]}
```

The key represents the value x or y. And their arrays the way they are all connected to each other. Example: `1` is connected to `3`, `3` is connected do `1, 8, 7, 6, 4` esc.

I've made a function that gives you the number of jumps to get from x to y.

```
def jumps(x, y, network):
x={x}
for i in range(1, len(network)):
    x=neighbors(x, network)
    if(y in x):
        return i

def neighbors(x, network):
seen=[]
for krizisce in x:
    for izvoz in network[krizisce]:
        if izvoz not in doslej and izvoz not in seen:
            seen.append(izvoz)
return {x for x in seen}
```

But I'd like to get the shortest array of keys from x to y.

For example if I pick 2 values that are far from each other like: `1` and `15`
I'd like to get the shortest path from `1 -> 15`. That would be `[1, 3, 8, 16, 15]`

Comment: This is Dijkstra.

Comment: Look for breadth-first search implementations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard case of finding shortest path and has implementations all over internet.

If you would like to understand you can look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

If you need a implementation fast, this seems to resemble your implementation a lot: https://gist.github.com/econchick/4666413

Comment: I made a implementation of the Dijkstra's algorithm thank's for the anwser